# How do I permanently delete data from a game when I delete it from my iPhone/ipad

Tags: ios-appstore

I have been trying for weeks now to delete a game and all of its data and every time I do this and install the game again it comes back with the previous data. I want to delete the game and start again as a new customer with no pre-existing data. Although it says it will remove the game and all of the data when trying to delete it does not.

Is there a way to permanently delete the data when I delete the game from the iPad and iPhone?

Comment: This question has no general answer but if you add the name of the game (and maybe also mention whether it is using Game Center or another Cloud solution) I'm quite sure that somebody here will be able to help you.

Answer (score 6):

If the game is saving game data via iCloud, the data might have not been deleted when you removed the app from your iOS device.

Go to **Settings > General > Usage**

There will be a section called **iCloud** with a **Manage Storage** option. Tapping this will load all your data stored on iCloud.

Under the **Documents & Data section**, check to see if your game has data saved to iCloud. If it does, simply tap on it and tap on the edit button in the top right hand corner to bring up the Delete prompt.

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 8, just go to Game Center app > Games > swipe left on games you want to remove and tap the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide apps from that list by going to iTunes on your computer (you don't have to connect the iPad, just log in to your iTunes account):

1. Click the iTunes Store button.
2. Then click on the "purchased" link either on the bottom under Features or on the top right under Quick Links (that's for iTunes 11, it's somewhere else on older versions but still easy to find).
3. Find the app you want to hide, hover your mouse over the icon and an "x" will appear in the upper left corner.
4. Click the "x" and the app will be hidden on purchased list on Apple servers.

Now you can check your iPad. Open the App Store, go to Purchased and check if the app is gone. If it's still there you just need to refresh the list. Close the App Store app, double click the home button, press and hold the app icon and close it (the "-" button in the upper left corner). Now the purchased list will be refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

sign out your apple ID from Game Center in iOS setting menu. Delete the app completely and press yes if it asks for removing data. reinstall a fresh copy of it from app store not itunes. run the app. use it for a while. reactivate apple ID and press no button on game run if it asks for retrieving previous data.

Answer (score -1):

Try going into iTunes, goto Store, App Store, and remove it from there as well.

It's worth a shot!

Comment: This sounds as if you propose to the delete the app from the store, which is probably not the intention. Can you add some more details including links to screenshots to clarify this?

Answer (score -1):

Deleting Apps From iPhone

Touch the app and hold your finger down until all the apps start to jiggle. You will see a circled "x" in the upper left corner. Tap it to delete an app. When done press the Home button.

You cannot delete any pre-installed iOS app.

If there is No 'X' on any apps you have Downloaded... then check in Restrictions... Settings > General > Restrictions > Deleting Apps  =  Off / On

If the app is in iTunes, then you delete the app in iTunes (Select the App and Press Delete on your Keyboard). If you then sync with your iDevice, the app will also be deleted from your iDevice.